I am doing a SpringMVCProject, but when I want to run it on the server, it shows that UnsatisfiedDependencyException
I think it started with "Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister."
This problem then make the eclipse can't create bean named sessionFactory. Below are code from springcfg.xml.
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.code.mvc.entity"></property>
    </bean>

This problem then make the eclipse can't create bean neamed usersdao. Below are code in springcfg.xml
Below are code in UsersDAO.java
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

This problem then make the eclipse can't create bean neamed usersService. Below are code from UsersService.
@Autowired
private IUsers userdao;

This problem then make the eclipse can't create bean neamed userController. Below are code from UsersController.
@Autowired
private IUsersService userservice;

